# C++: Is it possible to have a template class which represents a conditional reference to a resource?

Tags: c++, memory-management, data-structures, unique-ptr

So sometimes I want an object to have a reference to a shared resource (let's say something of type `A`), or *alternatively* to have its own copy of an `A`.

Furthermore the object may find itself inserted and manipulated inside of containers (`vector`, `list`, `set`).

So far what I know is that I will want to use an implementation of `unique_ptr` if I have a polymorphic type that is to be in a container. So for a class `HasAnA` which owns an `A` to be able to be placed inside a container while still allowing its `A`'s to also be `B`'s (`B` in this case being a derived class of `A`), it must be like this:

```
class A {
  virtual void a() { std::cout << "A" << endl; }
  payloadA payload;
}; 
class B: public A {
  void a() { std::cout << "A(B)" << endl; }
  void b() { std::cout << "B" << endl; }
  payloadB payload;
};
class HasAnA {
  std::unique_ptr<A> my_A; // this allows me to build a std::vector<HasAnA>
  OtherStuff my_other_stuff;
};
```

So this is great, what I'm looking for is how to implement a class I'll call `RefersAnA`. I'd like for a `RefersAnA` to either have ownership of its own A, OR refer to an A owned by something else.

Let's see.

```
class RefersAnA {
  std::unique_ptr<A> my_A; // represents my own A: when I die, this A is dealloc'd
  A* not_my_A;             // someone else's A. 
  OtherStuff my_other_stuff;
  RefersAnA () {
    // in here is code that would skip initializing my_A if a valid A* was provided.
  }
};
```

To me this isn't really as friendly as I would like. Could I make some sort of template class which abstracts the notion of "either being a unique ptr to the resource or a raw ptr to the resource"? It needs one bit to say which of the two it is, and one pointer.

Comment: Can't you just use another type of pointer like a `shared_ptr`, which can either be the only pointer to that object or one of multiple?

Comment: I love C++ simply for this kind of terminology... The title is just beautiful (NO)

Comment: `unique_ptr` supports custom deleters.  Now all you need to do is to write one named `delete_me_maybe`.

Comment: @Jasper I think you're right. I think using shared_ptr for everything would prevent the problem I'm having in the first place, at the cost of having reference counting where it is not needed.

Comment: @StevenLu the overhead of `shared_ptr`s is negligable unless you are working with really large amounts of really small objects

Comment: And you are right again! Now I know sometimes it's good to be lazy as a programmer, but I can't help caring about not using a `shared_ptr` if I actually don't need its features.

Comment: @StevenLu: Fair enough. As an academic exercise it's a fine question. As long as you know that's what it is.

Comment: Well I think it's probably better to just use a `shared_ptr` everywhere and only start looking around for ways to make stuff more optimal when that stuff actually matters. It's just that I'm always trying to learn how to use everything the "right way".

Comment: Does a unique_ptr with a deleter also take up the same space as a shared_ptr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an idea:

```
struct RefersOrOwns
{
    std::unique_ptr<T> own;
    T & ref;

    RefersOrOwns() : own(new T), ref(*own) { }

    RefersOrOwns(T & t) : ref(t) { }
};
```

<sub>(Instead of `own(new T)` I would of course prefer `own(make_unique<T>())`, but that's a separate issue.)</sub>

Comment: Hmm okay. so I'd just use the ref to look it up. Looks pretty good. So this would be a template (start the declaration with `template <class T>`)?

Comment: This is not different in any substantial way from the code presented in the question with a `unique_ptr<A>` and an `A*`.  It isn't space efficient the way the question requested, either.

Comment: True, but it lets me templatize it so I can rather easily make one for any type I wish. And I wasn't able to come up with that on my own. so it does help. However the situation is probably that I'll have many instances referring to something and only a few having their own copy, it will be inefficient to have each and every one have a `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: You will need *some* kind of state to describe whether your resource is owned by you or not. There's no getting around that.

Comment: @Kerrek: Right, and as the question said, you need one bit.  Probably you will use an entire byte for that, but no need for more.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Practically, the distinction between one bit, one byte and one machine-word is going to be negligible, though. The alignment of the whole thing is going to be on the pointer anyway.